# Typescript: Type predicate always return never

Tags: javascript, typescript, discriminated-union

I am attempting to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), specifically the `isSomeId` function, to narrow down the type of an array of `SomeU` objects based on the key property. The goal is to find an item with the key equal to `Keys.SOME_ID`. However, it seems that the `isSomeId` function is giving me a below error:

> A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
> Type '{ key: Keys.SOME_ID; type: FilterType; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SomeU'.
> Type '{ key: Keys.SOME_ID; type: FilterType; value: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ key: Keys; type: FilterType.ONE_OF; value: string[]; }'.
> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
> Type 'FilterType' is not assignable to type 'FilterType.ONE_OF'.

I have followed the TypeScript documentation on type predicates and created the `isSomeId` function accordingly. I expected this function to correctly infer the type, but it seems like something is not working as intended.

Additionally, I'm exploring the possibility of inferring the expected type directly from the `SomeU` type. I attempted to use the [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility function for this purpose, but it consistently returns never. To illustrate, I tried transforming the type predicate function to something like the following:

```js
function isSomeId(a: SomeU): a is Extract<SomeU, { key: Keys.SOME_ID }>
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue and get the correct type inference for variable s would be greatly appreciated. Attaching link to the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=9&pln=13&pc=12#code/KYOwrgtgBA0sCeBnKBvAUFTUDKB5AsgKID6AcgIJFQC8UARHkWZYXQDQZaMkCSAIjXrdi-dmgC%20aNKEhQAYgEsANgBdgAJwAq8AA7BUnTIQCKAVXIAZQXRPmLYrFB6kAwhdN9C1524%20sOjrikJLhy1kEhcnQSUiq6%20tgA9hDApjSGUAA%20qFAA1ggAXLAIiADcUHF6RYqqGtp6AHS2lmxQAG4AhkpgwEWIKuoKIADmko7ZKHmFxUjllb3yympa8Q0%207p6tnd0L-YMjY1gTU-BFcLMV8dVLdasRxKFbXT19A0PDANoAulDipbHxKDkQRJFKmb7-NAAMzAIAAxioFIkQFAFIhQcAeAATADqChUAAtCABHMBderAAAUHSKGNMAEoih1UchJvlTjNEA1hPxWvNrrUVnonjtXvthr8DI51MAVGB1CiOg12TRqLRzlyeQIAGTaqBK%20aq2g1ZYUppmSz-SRoOHI-pQRDJYDkdTqIrA2gfDJs6Ya7kEXh8PlXRaCs3NCwil70R0pOjiAJYH0cv3CChEYNVUOm1YRqMLOix4DxxOYZNnEr%20pjpwiZhYm26Ne6PdrPBYfADkRY7XwTaC%20kNtIHtyFoRZd6gaUKGWMpaIx2LxhJJZKUFPppSAA) as well.

```js
enum Keys {
    SOME_NAME = "SOME_NAME",
    SOME_ID = "SOME_ID",
}

enum FilterType {
    EQUAL = "EQUAL",
    INCLUDE = "INCLUDE",
    ONE_OF = "ONE_OF"
}

type SomeU =
    | { key: Keys; type: FilterType.EQUAL, value: string}
    | { key: Keys; type: FilterType.INCLUDE, value: string}
    | { key: Keys; type: FilterType.ONE_OF, value: string[] };

type A = SomeU[];

function isSomeId(a: SomeU): a is { key: Keys.SOME_ID, type: FilterType, value: string } {
    return a.key === Keys.SOME_ID && a.type === FilterType.EQUAL;
}

const someArr: A = [
    { key: Keys.SOME_ID, type: FilterType.EQUAL, value: "some"},
    { key: Keys.SOME_NAME, type: FilterType.EQUAL, value: "some"},
    { key: Keys.SOME_NAME, type: FilterType.ONE_OF, value: ['some']},
];

const s = someArr.find(isSomeId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate function is returning `type: FilterType` instead of `type: FilterType.EQUAL`, which is the main thing I think you should adjust, especially since that is what you are checking in your function body.

```js
function isSomeIdWithEqualType(
    a: SomeU
): a is { key: Keys.SOME_ID; type: FilterType.EQUAL; value: string } {
    return a.key === Keys.SOME_ID && a.type === FilterType.EQUAL;
}
```

As the error says, your predicate function's return type must be assignable to whatever your parameter is.

Here is what you are returning (I'm expanding your enums)

```js
{ 
    key: Keys.SOME_ID; 
    type: FilterType.EQUAL | FilterType.INCLUDE | FilterType.ONE_OF;
    value: string;
}
```

That isn't a valid type within `SomeU`. Namely,

```js
{ 
    key: Keys.SOME_ID; 
    type: FilterType.ONE_OF;
    value: string;
}
```

Is not a valid `SomeU`.

If you somehow *did* want to return all enums in `type`, you'd need to separate out the ones that don't have `value: string`, e.g.

```js
function isSomeIdWithEqualType(
    a: SomeU
): a is
    | { key: Keys.SOME_ID; type: FilterType.EQUAL | FilterType.INCLUDE; value: string }
    | { key: Keys.SOME_ID; type: FilterType.ONE_OF; value: string[] } {
    return a.key === Keys.SOME_ID && a.type === FilterType.EQUAL;
}
```

My guess is that you just had a typo, but I'm not sure how useful the above predicate function would be.